# unable to insert multiple group or person in Sharepoint custom list

Tags: custom-list

I could not update/insert the column with multiples group or person, it can only insert/update 1 group or person.

```
function updateListItem(item, id) {

var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Tracker');
oListItem = oList.getItemById(id);
oListItem.set_item('GroupMembers', item);

oListItem.update();

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {

alert('Item updated!');
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());console.log(args)
}

var t = new Array();
t.push(lookupValue.set_lookupId(23))
t.push(lookupValue.set_lookupId(44))
updateListItem(t, 110) <--- will throw unknown error

updateListItem("23;#44", 110) <--- will only insert 23
```

if there is any wrong with the code?
Thank you in advance.

Regards,
Xiu Yu

Answer (score 0):

You have to use like below. Basically for multiple fields you also need to pass login name and format should below like

```
User1_ID + ';#' + User1_Name + ';#' + User2_ID + ';#' + User2_Name;


var userField = this.user1.get_id() + ";#" + this.user1.get_loginName()+";"+this.user2.get_id() + ";#" + this.user2.get_loginName();
listItem.set_item('UserField', userField);
listItem.Update();
list.Update();
```